# Permutation and combination and binary numbers

Tags: permutations, combinations, binary

what is the sum(in base 10) of all natural numbers less than 64 which have exactly three ones in their base 2 representation.
answer given -630 
I just need a starting point like from where should I start any hint?? Also I know only basic binary-decimal conversions so please answer accordingly.

Comment: I take it this is for a combinatorics class, and so you've covered combinations?

Comment: Thanks to Brian tung it turns out that the problem is very easy and the sum is simply- $$(2^0+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5)10=63×10$$ where the numbers inside the bracket account for the contribution of each bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since there are only $63$ natural numbers less than $64$, one way you could proceed is by brute force.  These are the numbers that can be represented in binary by six bits.  There are therefore only $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ different numbers that qualify.  Write them all out, and then add them.

A slightly more clever way to proceed is to consider how many numbers have a $1$ in the most significant binary (MSB) position—the one corresponding to decimal $32$.  That leaves two bits to go in the remaining five positions.  There are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ of those, so the MSB position contributes $320$.  That isn't the sum of those ten numbers, but it *is* the sum of the contribution of that bit from those ten numbers.

Similarly, there are ten qualifying numbers that contain the second most significant bit, so they contribute $160$, and so on to the least significant bit.  What is the total contribution?

Comment: @Freelancer $5 \choose 2$ means "5 choose 2", the $5C2$ you mentioned.

Comment: How would this account for duplicates? Like, $111000$ (when you count the first and two other digits) and $111000$ (when you count the second digit and any two other digits) are both same...